# Create an XML assertion sso-like with Spring

Tags: spring, single-sign-on, saml, assertion, idp

I'm kinda newbie into the spring world, and I'm trying to run a POC for a SAML SSO assertion-type,
I've implemented locally this project https://github.com/vdenotaris/spring-boot-security-saml-sample
And ran it against SSOCircle, but eventually, I'm gonna need to use my own IDP what I'm trying to do right now, doesn't involve actually validating the user, I want the demo project from the GitHub to point to a different spring project.

That part is actually done, I've added to my IDP-demo page an XML-metadata which is consumed by the Service provider, then in my IDP-demo, I type any email address and it should take me back to the Service Provider (the vdenotaris sample project) with a valid assertion.

How can I dynamically generate this XML assertion? I've read the spring docs and the SAML docs with no luck, If anyone can point me into the right place or even the proper documentation I'll be thankful.

Comment: Spring Security SAML is an SAML SP implementation. This means it does not create SAML Responses that includes SAML assertions but consumes them. You may direclty look at OpenSAML library to create a SAML Response. However it's quite an effort to build a spec compliant SAML IdP. You may just use the older open-source OpenAM, this allows you to setup a SAML IdP in less than 10 minutes.

Comment: Thanks, @BernhardThalmayr but in my case, I have an existing project that works as an SSO for other projects, I want to add the SSO response from that project, all I need is to be able to generate a valid XML response and sign it with a certificate.
I'll take a look at OpenSAML